# How to get button value in spring form?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

i should use onsubmit method.

```
<form:form action="/ProjectEnvironments/Submitcontinue"  onsubmit="return validateTransGrid(this)" method="POST" >
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><input value="Submit & Continue" title="Submit & Continue" class="formbutt" type="submit" /></td>
            <td class="width5px"></td>
            <td><input value="Submit" title="Submit" class="formbutt" type="submit" /></td>
            <td class="width5px"></td>
            <td><input value="Clear" title="Clear" class="formbutt" type="submit"  name="clearAction"/></td>
            <td class="width5px"><br /> <br /></td>
            <td><input value="Cancel" title="Cancel" class="formbutt" type="submit"  name="cancelAction"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>`
```

**javascript:**

```
function validateTransGrid(e){
    alert(e.value);
    return false;
}
```

I unable to get button value.

Comment: Have you checked the error on console ?

Comment: why going to console this method return false,so no need..need to check button event value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
function validateTransGrid(e){
   var submitName =  $(":input[type=submit]:focus")[0].value;
   alert(submitName );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, Use hidden variables inside your spring form.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="buttonValue" name="dynamicButtonValue" />
</form>
```

And in your javascript,

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("buttonValue").value = "saveandcontinue";
};
document.getElementById("myBtn1").onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("buttonValue").value = "save";
};
function validateTransGrid(){
   var buttonValue = document.getElementById("buttonValue").value;
   alert(buttonValue);
   return false;
}
```

Now when you submit your form, you will get submitted button value in spring. 
**Note**: I have assigned id to your buttons. Hope this helps..

Comment: is it possible from event

Comment: sorry calling method is validateTransgrid.alert gives empty value

Comment: post your updated code after implementing this code.